# Tags on StackOverflow Careers in the Experience section are too narrow to read

Tags: bug, tags, jobs

There seems to be a visual bug with tags in the Experience section of StackOverflow Careers.  Tested on Chrome and Safari and both appear bugged.  Tags appear fine in all other sections of the Careers page and other sites (SO, Meta SO, etc).

[image: Tag bug]